# Appended Form Element only returns one set of data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i tried to return multiple Form Elements with the same name, however i only get the last element not all of them. In my View it works and shows all elements, once i hit submit only the last Element returns (in this case 3 times). Why is that?

forms.py:

```
class GroupAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='' ,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    page_name = forms.CharField(label='' ,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'rows': '4', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    page_street =  forms.CharField(label='' ,widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'rows': '4', 'class': 'form-control'}))
    add_button = forms.BooleanField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'rows': '4', 'class': 'form-control'}))

    class Meta: 
        model = GroupManagement
        fields = ['email', 'page_name', 'page_street', 'add_button']
```

View.py

```
for items in locationdata:
        show_name.append(items[1])
        show_street.append(items[2])
        name = items[1]
        street = items[2]
        form = GroupAddForm(request.POST or None, initial={"page_name": name, "page_street": street, "email": email})
        forms.append(form)

    for item in forms:
        if item.is_valid():
            email = item.cleaned_data.get("email")
            page_name = item.cleaned_data.get("page_name")
            page_street = item.cleaned_data.get("page_street")
            add_button = item.cleaned_data.get("add_button")    
            if add_button == true: 
    //// do stuff



    context = {
    'names': names,
    'street': street,
    'group_name_form': group_name_form,
    'locationdata': locationdata,
    'forms': forms,
    }
```

Template:

```
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <form method="POST" action=""> {% csrf_token %}
                                                        {{group_name_form.as_p}}

<div class="col-md-6 pull-left">
   {% for items in names %}

   <p style="text-align:left;"> {{items.0}}  {{items.1}} </p>

      {% endfor %}
     </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
    {% for items in forms %}
    {{items.as_p}} 

       {% endfor %}
    </div>
 </div>

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Gruppe erstellen"></form>
   </div>
```

Comment: I can't understand what you're doing here at all. What's the point of the forms, if you're just creating then then saving them? Why not create the objects directly?

Comment: The Checkbutton is currently missing, that's why it's probably looking weird right now. The form object is only saved if the check button is clicked and added to a groupname

Comment: What check button? You're not even using a template here. Maybe you should show some real code.

Comment: Should be easier to understand now.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean by real code? It's not finished because the values  are wrong, but apart from that it's  written in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to have multiple instances of the same form class is to use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).

Comment: Thanks, haven't completly figured out how to use it yet ;) but seems to be what i need